# How to Change Focuse in Edit text after entering 2 Character

Tags: android, focus, android-edittext, onfocus

Hello I have Difficulty to Change focus between two edit text.
this task perform in Android 4.2 very well but Same task done in Samsung Duos Android 4.0.1 it's not working please give me Suggestions.
Thank You

My Code is:

```
first_number_from.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (first_number_from.getText().length() == 2)
                    second_number_from.requestFocus();

                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: try this                                                            if (first_number_from.getText().toString().length() == 2) second_number_from.requestFocus();

Comment: It's not work in Samsung Duos Android 4.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a text changed listener

```
first_number_from.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,int before, int count)  {
                if(first_number_from.getText().toString().length() == 2) {
                    second_number_from.requestFocus();
                }
            }
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                            int count, int after) {}

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }

        });
```

Comment: You should debug it, and tell us more about what doesn't work. are you sure you call .getText().toString().length() on edittext instead of .getText().lenght()?

Answer (score 0):

Try `TextWatcher` instead of `onKeyListener`

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
{
if (first_number_from.getText().toString().length() == 2)
{
     second_number_from.requestFocus();
}
}
```